# Filling table from several input files

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I have the following scenario: several csv files contain different columns of the same table. Can I fill the redshift table from them somehow, and, ideally, with the help of the data pipeline? I couldn't find the way I can achieve this. Can anyone help with the solution or maybe simple example if it's possible?

Comment: As far as I know, in case of copy statement, it will allow you to use manifest files to load multiple files together but with same columns ordering. In case of different columns ordering or different number of columns, you may want to load them individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by converting your csv files into json format prior to their load. Then particular Json tag will not be found in the file: copy will just dismiss it.